# How to automate OPENVPN login

Tags: bash

I created a very simple bash script.  The first line of the script after #!/bin/bash accesses my vpn service using an OPENVPN file provided by the VPN Vendor.  It works as expected and then waits for data entry of my username and once entered expects my password.

I used the echo command to provide the required responses but they never occur.  Open VPN just sits there waiting for my username.   If I hit enter twice then OPENVPN terminates and my script completes by echoing the username and password.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/us-dtw.prod.xxxxxxx.com_udp.ovpn 
echo $'\r'
printf "                    xf3Z3ZY6xxxxxxxxEuRDmh"
echo $'\r'
echo "                      nvn7B5kxxxxhxxJstRU"
```

What could be causing my script to hang and not execute the echo commands until OPENVPN terminates?

Maybe there is a way to pipe the text but I am really new to this.

Found an example that works correctly to automate the VPN logon process: https://help.anonine.com/support/solutions/articles/5000613671-how-do-i-save-my-username-password-in-openvpn-for-automatic-login-

Comment: Why make us guess about what in in your `bash` script? Please update your Q to include a sanitized (no personal information!) version of your script. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: When you put the `echo` line _after_ the `sudo openvpn` line, you're telling `echo` to run after `openvpn` exits.

Comment: Anyhow, openvpn has well-supported programmatic interfaces designed to be used for retrieving credentials (or, rather, multiple such interfaces -- one with a socket API, another in which it calls a named process, and probably more I'm forgetting). Don't hack something up yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openvpn will by default be using the TTY to get input, not standard input.

Have you looked at the `--askpass` option to openvpn?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with --askpass.  I will research it, thanks.

Comment: This is how it's done, hope it can help someone else.